# Python: insert dynamic value into binary regex pattern?

Tags: python, regex, string, arrays

I'm trying to compile an expression that essentially does the following:

```
exp = b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{%i}' % length
exp
b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{32}'
```

Unfortunately, this returns the error:

```
exp = b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{%i}' % length
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'int'
```

I tried:

```
exp = bytes('[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{%i}' % length,'utf-8')
exp
b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xc3\xbf]{32}'
```

which is not what I want:

```
exp == b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{32}'
False
```

I know I must be overlooking something simple. Help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latin-1 encoding seems to work:

```
bytes('[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xFF]{%i}' % length,'latin-1')
b'[\x00]{2}[\x00-\xff]{34}'
```